# The country of the app in an Apple App Store

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, submit

I am developing an application. When I click "View on App Store" in the iTunes Connect, it suggests that I change the App Store location (e.g., to the US) to show my app. I **don't want to change app store of my apple id, but to change the app store for my app itself**, in the itunes connect settings. Where can I find them?

Comment: Is the apple id correct in device? Is the app available to every country?

Comment: Actually, it is not published yet.I am just testing installed version on the device. Yes, it's correct and available. Maybe, being in the App Store it will be in the right place.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Oddie I want to be sure that my app will be available for my local App Store cause I have everything checked (for all countries), and I was asked to switch the App Store anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you checked "Available in all territories" your app will be available in all App Stores around the world. Testing it manually is a rather cumbersome task due to caching and how switching the stores works on iPhones/iPads vs. iTunes.

[image]

In the iTunes app on your Mac/Windows machine you can simply switch the stores by clicking on the country flag icon in the bottom right. If your currently logged-in Apple ID is not valid with that store, you will get automatically logged out.

On your iPad/iPhone you have to have an Apple ID valid with the respective store. Sign out with your "old" Apple ID and then in with the new one. You will automatically get switched to the right store.

The easiest way to test if your app is available in different stores is via the web preview. (I'd use Chrome, so Safari doesn't instantly try to open iTunes for that):

Get your App Store link and simply change the store front code, e.g.:
https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/id529479190?mt=8 => German Store
https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/id529479190?mt=8 => Chinese Store
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id529479190?mt=8 => US Store

(You can find all the storefront codes at the end of this page: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store/)

Answer (score 1):

When Application is live then you can see on ItunesConnect by clicking on "View on App Store".

Answer (score 0):

in iTunes Connect select Pricing and Availability and choose the appropriate App Store locations.

see [Changing the Territories Rights Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html) for screenshots and details.

Comment: I have all options checked there. So why was I asked to move?